# JavaScript: Convert Pseudo Code into JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, html, code-snippets

JavaScript

I have considered the following pseudo code:

```
for answer in answers {
    if(answer in selectedAnswers){
        if(selectedAnswer in rightAnswers)
             // Code if answer is right
        }    
        else {
            // Code if answer is wrong
        }
    }
}
```

And I tried to implement the code in JavaScript, but somehow I don't want to succeed.

```js
currentAnswers = Object.keys(currentQuestion.answers);
currentSelectedAnswers[buttonClicked] = this.id.split('-')[5]; 
currentRightAnswers = currentQuestion.rights;

    for(var answer in currentAnswers) 
    {
        if(currentSelectedAnswers.includes(answer))
        {
            if(currentRightAnswers.includes(currentSelectedAnswers))
            {
                console.log("TRUE");
            }
            else 
            { 
                console.log("FALSE");
            } 
        }
    }


A snippet of a question of my JSON File:

                    "answers": {
                        "1": '...sind eigenständig ausführbare Programme.',
                        "2": '...müssen in der gleichen Programmiersprache wie die Anwendung geschrieben worden sein.',
                        "3": '...müssen in Assemblersprache geschrieben worden sein.',
                        "4": '...können beim Compilieren des Programms statisch gelinkt werden.',
                        "5": '...können zur Laufzeit des Programms dynamisch gelinkt werden.',
                        "6": '...müssen zum Compilieren des Programms im Quelltext vorliegen.'
                    },
                    "rights": {
                        "1": "4",
                        "2": "5" 
                    },
```

But I get the following error:

[image: error]

I hope someone can help me?

Ich want to highlight the two right answers and hightlight the selected two wrong answers.

currentAnswers are declared out of any function at the top....

currentSelectedAnswers is declared in the buttonClick Event of the Answer Button, if I click the answer button the function with the for loop will execude...

currentRightAnswers is declared in the function with the for loop at the top of it....

```js
THE VALIDATION FUNCTION WHICH CHECK IF THE ANSWERS ARE WRONG OR RIGHT
var currentSelectedAnswers = [];
var currentAnswers = [];
var currentAnswers = Object.keys(currentQuestion.answers);

function validateEasyTwoAnswersQuestionAnswer() {
    console.log("validateEasyTwoAnswersQuestionAnswer");
    $(".answer-btn").hide();
    var currentRightAnswers = [];
    currentRightAnswers = currentQuestion.rights;
    for(var answer in currentAnswers) 
    {
        if(currentSelectedAnswers.includes(answer))
        {
            if(currentRightAnswers.includes(currentSelectedAnswers))
            {
                console.log("TRUE");
            }
            else 
            { 
                console.log("FALSE");
            } 
        }
    }
    $(".continue-btn").show();
}



IF AN ANSWER CLICKED THE CLICK EVENT WILL EXECUDE
button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            if(buttonClicked == 2)
            {
              e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                buttonClicked++;
                selectAnswer(this);
                console.log(this.id);
                currentSelectedAnswers[buttonClicked] = this.id.split('-')[5];
                console.log(currentSelectedAnswers);
            }
        });
```

Comment: what are `currentQuestion`, `currentSelectedAnswers` and `buttonClicked` - where are they declared

Comment: I have added to the post

Comment: you still haven't shown code with those variables, just vague descriptions you may understand but mean nothing

Comment: I added some code again...

Answer (score 3):

> `currentRightAnswers.includes` is not a function

I believe you are trying to call the function [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). It's part of `Array` objects, but `currentRightAnswers` is not an array. It's just an Object.

A quick fix would be to define the property `rights` as an `Array`, like this, in your JSON file (Notice the `[]` instead of `{}`:

```
{
  "answers": {
    "1": '...sind eigenständig ausführbare Programme.',
    "2": '...müssen in der gleichen Programmiersprache wie die Anwendung geschrieben worden sein.',
    "3": '...müssen in Assemblersprache geschrieben worden sein.',
    "4": '...können beim Compilieren des Programms statisch gelinkt werden.',
    "5": '...können zur Laufzeit des Programms dynamisch gelinkt werden.',
    "6": '...müssen zum Compilieren des Programms im Quelltext vorliegen.'
  },
  "rights": [
    "4",
    "5" 
  ]
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. The error is away but I have another problem. The for loop with the if's does not the right thing...can you help me to improve that?

And how can I solve it, when I have two rights for more than one answer...so I have